# Why are my list elements starting at the bottom and not the top?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've created a UL for a dropdown menu in the mobile-friendly version of a react.js script; however, when I drop the menu down the list starts from the bottom-up and not the top-down. Any ideas? I've attached a photo and some code.

**NAVAR COMPONENT .JS FILE**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button } from './Button';
import './Navbar.css';

function Navbar() {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
    const [button, setButton] = useState(true);

    const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
    const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);
    const showButton = () => {
        if(window.innerWidth <= 960){
            setButton(false);
        } else {
            setButton(true);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        showButton();
    },[]);

    window.addEventListener('resize', showButton);

    return (
        <>
            <nav className="navbar">
                <div className="navbar-container">
                    <Link to="/" className='navbar-logo' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                        RentalsFriend&nbsp;
                        <i className="fas fa-home"></i>
                    </Link>
                    <div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
                        <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
                    </div>
                    <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to='/listings' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                                Listings
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to='/landlords' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                                Landlords
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to='/services' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                                Services
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to='/sign-up' className='nav-links-mobile' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                                Sign Up
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    {button && <Button buttonStyle='btn--outline'>SIGN UP</Button>}
                </div>
            </nav>  
        </>
    );
}

export default Navbar
```

**

- .CSS FILE

**

```
    .navbar {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(28, 27, 27) 0%, rgb(26, 23, 23) 100%);
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  
  .navbar-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    max-width: 1500px;
  }
  
  .navbar-logo {
    color: #fff;
    justify-self: start;
    margin-left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .fa-typo3 {
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
  
  .nav-menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60vw;
    justify-content: end;
    margin-right: 2rem;
  }
  
  .nav-item {
    height: 80px;
  }
  
  .nav-links {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .nav-links:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  }
  
  .fa-bars {
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .nav-links-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .nav-item {
      position: relative;
    }
  
    .nav-menu {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 100%;
      height: 90vh;
      position: absolute;
      top: 80px;
      left: -100%;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
  
    .nav-menu.active {
      background: #242222;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  
    .nav-links {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 2rem;
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
    }
  
    .nav-links:hover {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #242424;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
  
    .navbar-logo {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      transform: translate(25%, 50%);
    }
  
    .menu-icon {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  
    .fa-times {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
  
    .nav-links-mobile {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 2rem auto;
      border-radius: 4px;
      width: 80%;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 14px 20px;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    }
  
    .nav-links-mobile:hover {
      background: #fff;
      color: #242424;
      transition: 250ms;
    }
  }
```

[Navbar in full-size format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFmEV.jpg)

[Navbar in small-size format with drop-down open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ksjo3.jpg)

Comment: Check the .nav-menu  justify-content: end; property.

Comment: @BojanBedrač you're a god. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I can recommend this free course for mastering Flexbox. https://flexbox.io/